# XML handing: how can I access this xml file in its dictionary form

Tags: python, xml

I have an `xml` file, and I want to access this file as a dictionary, such as the keys first and other can be access and their values across this dictionary.

## This is what I tried

```
import xmltodict
  
with open('E:/Research work/My connect/Sam/CETM50 - 2022_3 - Assignment Data/user_data.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    my_xml = file.read()
  
my_dict = xmltodict.parse(my_xml)

# This is what I got
OrderedDict([('users',
              OrderedDict([('user',
                            [OrderedDict([('@firstName', 'Iain'),
                                          ('@lastName', 'Dixon'),
                                          ('@age', '64'),
                                          ('@sex', 'Male'),
                                          ('@retired', 'False'),
                                          ('@dependants', '2'),
                                          ('@marital_status', 'single'),
                                          ('@salary', '56185'),
                                          ('@pension', '0'),
                                          ('@company', 'Hudson PLC'),
                                          ('@commute_distance', '14.1'),
                                          ('@address_postcode', 'G2J 0FH')]),
                             OrderedDict([('@firstName', 'Jayne'),
                                          ('@lastName', 'Wilson'),
                                          ('@age', '69'),
                                          ('@sex', 'Female'),
                                          ('@retired', 'False'),
                                          ('@dependants', '1'),
                                          ('@marital_status', 'divorced'),
                                          ('@salary', '36872'),
                                          ('@pension', '0'),
                                          ('@company',
                                           'Wall, Reed and Whitehouse'),
                                          ('@commute_distance', '10.47'),
                                          ('@address_postcode', 'TD95 7FL')]) and so on.
```

## This is what I want

```
[{'firstName': 'Nicholas',
  'lastName': 'Spencer',
  'age': 71,
  'iban': 'GB43YKET96816855547287',
  'credit_card_number': '2221597849919620',
  'credit_card_security_code': '646',
  'credit_card_start_date': '03/18',
  'credit_card_end_date': '06/26',
  'address_main': '462 Marilyn radial',
  'address_city': 'Lynneton',
  'address_postcode': 'W4 0GW'},
 {'firstName': 'Gregory',
  'lastName': 'Knowles',
  'age': 91,
  'iban': 'GB53QKRK45175204753504',
  'credit_card_number': '4050437758955103343',
  'credit_card_security_code': '827',
  'credit_card_start_date': '11/21',
  'credit_card_end_date': '01/27',
  'address_main': '366 Brenda radial',
  'address_city': 'Ritafurt',
  'address_postcode': 'NE85 1RG'}]
```

Only standard Libraies are in use. How can this be done?

Comment: share user_data.xml in the post

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `attr_prefix=''` to `parse()` to get rid of the `@`.

The `OrderedDict` objects *are* dictionaries, and aren't usually necessary to convert to dicts explicitly.
You can use `dict()` to convert them to dicts.